# Gtk# Menu bar seems to conflict with GLWidget

Tags: c#, opengl, monodevelop, gtk#

I am trying to write a simple and basic modeling program using gtk# and opengl.  In order to be able to use both a gtk gui and opengl, I am using the glwidget.  Lately I've been having a problem with having both a menu bar and a glwidget in the same vbox (they are in different slots, but same vbox). Here is my code:

```
//MainWindow.cs
using System;
using Gtk;
using CubeGameModeler;
using OpenTK;
using OpenTK.Graphics.OpenGL;
using GLib;

public partial class MainWindow: Gtk.Window
{   
    public MainWindow (): base (Gtk.WindowType.Toplevel)
    {
        Build ();
    }
    protected void OnDeleteEvent (object sender, DeleteEventArgs a)
    {
        Application.Quit ();
        a.RetVal = true;
    }
    protected void OnExit (object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Application.Quit ();
    }
    protected void OnSaveAs (object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SaveWindow savewindow = new SaveWindow ();
        savewindow.Show ();
    }
    protected void OnSettings (object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SettingsWindow settingswindow = new SettingsWindow ();
        settingswindow.Show ();
    }
    protected void OnAbout (object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        AboutWindow aboutwindow = new AboutWindow ();
        aboutwindow.Show ();
    }
    protected void OnOpen (object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        OpenWindow openwindow = new OpenWindow ();
        openwindow.Show ();
    }
    protected void OnHelp (object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        HelpWindow helpwindow = new HelpWindow ();
        helpwindow.Show ();
    }
    protected void glwidget2_RenderFrame (object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        GL.Viewport (0, 0, 100, 100);
        GL.ClearColor (0.5f, 0.5f, 1.0f, 1.0f);
        GL.Clear (ClearBufferMask.ColorBufferBit);
        GL.MatrixMode (MatrixMode.Modelview);
        GL.LoadIdentity ();
    }

}
```

This is the code in my MainWindow.cs class.  I'm not worried about opengl rendering yet, I'm just trying to get the window to stay open for more than than a split second.  I don't know if this is a bug or if it just has to do with my crappy laptop.  I am using MonoDevelop on Debian Wheezy i386.  When I try to run the program, it opens for a split second and then closes.  When I look at the Application Output, this is what it says:

```
Loaded assembly: /home/mprogrammer/Documents/Monodevelop_Projects/CubeGameModeler/CubeGameModeler/bin/Debug/CubeGameModeler.exe
Loaded assembly: /usr/lib/mono/gac/gtk-sharp/2.12.0.0__35e10195dab3c99f/gtk-sharp.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /usr/lib/mono/gac/glib-sharp/2.12.0.0__35e10195dab3c99f/glib-sharp.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /usr/lib/mono/gac/atk-sharp/2.12.0.0__35e10195dab3c99f/atk-sharp.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /usr/lib/mono/gac/System/4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /usr/lib/mono/gac/gdk-sharp/2.12.0.0__35e10195dab3c99f/gdk-sharp.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /usr/lib/mono/gac/Mono.Posix/4.0.0.0__0738eb9f132ed756/Mono.Posix.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /home/mprogrammer/Documents/Monodevelop_Projects/CubeGameModeler/CubeGameModeler/bin/Debug/OpenTK.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /usr/lib/mono/gac/System.Drawing/4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a/System.Drawing.dll [External]
Stacktrace:

  at (wrapper managed-to-native) Gtk.Application.gtk_main () <IL 0x00022, 0xffffffff>
  at Gtk.Application.Run () <IL 0x00000, 0x0001f>
  at CubeGameModeler.MainClass.Main (string[]) [0x00011] in /home/mprogrammer/Documents/Monodevelop_Projects/CubeGameModeler/CubeGameModeler/Main.cs:13
  at (wrapper runtime-invoke) <Module>.runtime_invoke_void_object (object,intptr,intptr,intptr) <IL 0x00050, 0xffffffff>

Native stacktrace:

    /usr/bin/mono() [0x80e863d]
    /usr/bin/mono() [0x8128bac]
    /usr/bin/mono() [0x8064d1f]
    [0xb76f240c]
    /lib/i386-linux-gnu/i686/cmov/libpthread.so.0(__pthread_mutex_lock+0x1d) [0xb769618d]
    /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libX11.so.6(+0x2999d) [0xb64d599d]
    [0x156]

Debug info from gdb:


=================================================================
Got a SIGSEGV while executing native code. This usually indicates
a fatal error in the mono runtime or one of the native libraries 
used by your application.
=================================================================
```

I have determined through trial and error that the problem is with the menu bar, because if I leave it on the window, but make it invisible, the glwidget has no problem and the program continues to run.
If any more information is needed, please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

I've met the same problem. And not only with menu but with Button and Entry widgets too. I found the way to solve it.
Initialization of toolkit at program start moved out the problem for me.
Here is the code:

```
public static void Main (string[] args)
{
  using(Init())
  {
    Application.Init ();
    MainWindow win = new MainWindow ();
    win.Show ();
    Application.Run ();      
  }
}

private static OpenTK.Toolkit Init()
{
  return Toolkit.Init(new ToolkitOptions
  {
      Backend = PlatformBackend.PreferNative
  });
}
```